# Vifm background of highlighting changes inside tmux

Tags: tmux, vifm

I am using vifm inside tmux on Ubuntu 14.10. It looks great outside of tmux but inside tmux I have a problem with a highlighting line. I had almost the same problem with vim ([vim in tmux background color changes when paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427650/vim-in-tmux-background-color-changes-when-pagin)) but after applying `:set t_ut=` it works now.

Here is how vifm looks inside tmux (the highlighting line is supposed to take a whole line) 
[image]

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM` inside `tmux` session? There is no `:set t_ut=` solution in this case as vifm relies on ncurses to interact with terminal, while vim does this on its own. Still it partially depends on your color scheme and `$TERM`.

Comment: The value of `$TERM` was `xterm-256color`. I changed it to `screen-256color`. Now it works. Thank @xaizek for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `$TERM` inside `tmux` session was `xterm-256color`. I changed it to `screen-256color`. Now it works. Thanks @xaizek for the hint.