# vim in tmux will lose color schema when using `j` to move page down

Tags: vim, tmux

I am open vim in tmux in development, There is problem that when i using `j` to move page down, the color schema will lose, I record my operation as a video and uploaded to youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejNf2TPSc4E

normally the color schema should be following:

[image]

but when I trying to use `j` to move down, the spaces without contains words will lost and become white:

[image]

I am using stonewashed theme

Comment: The site is at https://github.com/altercation/solarized

Comment: https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/149 or
https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux

both handle similar issues

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, thanks, `export TERM=screen-256color` resolved the issue, should I closed this answer?

Comment: @Wooden Just mark your answer as correct one below. Maybe you get marked as duplicated, because the first related question on StackOverflow (on the right side) is basically the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427650/vim-in-tmux-background-color-changes-when-paging?rq=1) but that is not that bad.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo,that's ok, and thanks for your reply

Comment: you are welcome, glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export TERM=screen-256color` resolved the issue

Comment: I believe that you could also start tmux with the `-2` flag. `"Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours."`